# Unable to repo sync cyanogenmod source stuck at 99%

Tags: android

```
Fetching projects:  97% (505/520)  Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_media
Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_audio
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/stable/cm-13.0-ZNH2KB
Unexpected end of command stream
Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_media
Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_audio
Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_media
Fetching projects:  98% (510/520)  Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_audio
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/stable/cm-13.0-ZNH2KB
Unexpected end of command stream
Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_media
Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_audio
Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_media
Fetching projects:  99% (515/520)  Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_media
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/stable/cm-13.0-ZNH2KB
Unexpected end of command stream
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/stable/cm-13.0-ZNH2KB
Unexpected end of command stream
error: Cannot fetch CyanogenMod/android_device_qcom_sepolicy
error: Cannot fetch CyanogenMod/android_vendor_qcom_opensource_dataservices
error: Cannot fetch CyanogenMod/android_vendor_qcom_opensource_time-services
error: Cannot fetch CyanogenMod/android_vendor_qcom_opensource_dpm

error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? Some code? This is probably the worst question ever.

Comment: im trying to build cyanogenmod 13 from source. To that i need to download the cyanogenmod source from git. so i have executed 
repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b stable/cm-13.0-ZNH2KB. And after that i executed repo sync which will actually start downloading the source from repository. My question is that the syncing is stuck at 99% and i get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Use`--force-broken` or `-f` to recover from network errors.

So, use repo sync like this:

`repo sync -j8 -f`

If you still get errors, add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Difficulties syncing the source tree (TCP issues)
Symptom: repo sync hangs while syncing, often when it's completed 99% of the sync.

Cause: Some settings in the TCP/IP stack cause difficulties in some network environments, so that repo sync neither completes nor fails.

Fix: On Linux, enter the command:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=0
```

On macOS, disable the rfc1323 extension in the network settings.

https://source.android.com/setup/build/known-issues